# Proving that the sum of the squared radii of curvature of two curves is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I'm learning differential geometry, specifically the theory of curves, and need help with the following exercise:

> Consider the regular curve $\Gamma : \vec x = \vec x(s) \in C^4$ of $E^3$. If $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are the radii of curvature of $\Gamma_1 : \vec x(s) = \mathbf{T}(s)$ and $\Gamma_2 : \vec x(s) = \mathbf{B}(s)$ respectively, show that $\rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2 = 1$.

We use $\mathbf{T}(s)$ and $\mathbf{B}(s)$ to denote the tangent and binormal vectors, respectively.

I'm sorry for my lack of effort but unfortunely I wasn't able to do much. My first thought was to manipulate the Frenet–Serret formulas but I couldn't reach any useful result. Also, I don't understand the importance of the first sentence of the problem. $\Gamma, \Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are three different curves, so why is it important to know that $\Gamma \in C^4$ of $E^3$? We are only interested in the relationship between $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.

Comment: The problem should be $\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2=1$

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yes, absolutely. I corrected my original post. Thank you.

Comment: Is it easier now ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I was working all along with the correct formulation of the problem. This was an unfortunate typo. I'm still stuck.

Comment: I am too lazy to write out a full solution at the moment. But you need the formula for calculating the curvature of a curve not parameterized by arc length. Because the curves given by T and B are not arc length parameterized. Then use the Frenet formulas to find the derivatives. It does work out.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Throughout the book the author is using $s$  for a curve parameterized by arc length, so it is confusing here. Nevertheless I'm going to follow your steps and see if I can come up with the correct solution.

Comment: Yeah s is arc length for the ORIGINAL curve, but its not arc length for T and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete solution I indicated in the comments earlier, although OP has probably found it on his own by now.

The Frenet equations are
$$\dot{\mathbf{t}}=\kappa \mathbf{n}$$
$$\dot{\mathbf{n}}=-\kappa \mathbf{t}+\tau \mathbf{b}$$
$$\dot{\mathbf{b}}=-\tau\mathbf{n}.$$

Given a curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$ where $t$ need not be arc length,

$$\kappa_{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\dot{|\mathbf{r}} \times \ddot{\mathbf{r}}|}{|\dot{\mathbf{r}}|^3}$$

Taking first $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{
t}$ we have $$\dot{\mathbf{
t}}=\kappa \mathbf{n}$$
$$\ddot{\mathbf{
t}}=\dot{\kappa} \mathbf{n}+\kappa(-\kappa \mathbf{t}+\tau \mathbf{b})$$
$$=\dot{\kappa} \mathbf{n}-\kappa^2 \mathbf{t}+\kappa\tau \mathbf{b}$$

Now 
$$\dot{\mathbf{t}} \times \ddot{\mathbf{t}}=\kappa^3\mathbf{b}+\kappa^2\tau\mathbf{t}$$
so 
$$|\dot{\mathbf{t}} \times \ddot{\mathbf{t}}|=\sqrt{\kappa^6+\kappa^4\tau^2}$$
$$=\kappa^2\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}$$

And $$|\dot{\mathbf{t}}|^3=\kappa^3$$
So 
$$\kappa_{\mathbf{t}}=\frac{\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}}{\kappa}.$$

Similarly, 
$$\kappa_{\mathbf{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}}{|\tau|}.$$

The result is now clear.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a complete solution to the problem. Following your previous explanation I was also able to find the path to the correct solution. The fact that $\mathbf T$ and $\mathbf N$ are not parameterized by arc length does still confuses me though. I don't know if there is an easy way to understand this.

Comment: I am glad. Yeah $s$ is the arc length parameter for the original curve, $T$ and $B$ will have there own arc length parameters, which may be hard to calculate. In general non arc length parameterizations are forced on us in diff geo.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Note that the unit tangent vector for both the curves $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ is $\mathbf N(s)$. Now use the chain rule to compute the derivative of $\mathbf N$ with respect to the arclength of $\Gamma_1$ and with respect to the arclength of $\Gamma_2$. In particular, if $\sigma_i$ is the arclength of $\Gamma_i$, note that
$$\frac{d\mathbf N}{d\sigma_i} = \frac{\frac{d\mathbf N}{ds}}{\frac{d\sigma_i}{ds}},$$
and recall that $\dfrac{d\sigma_i}{ds}$ is the speed of the parametrized curve $\Gamma_i$.